# How to efficiently store different node types of an octree

Tags: c++, octree

I am struggling my way through implementing a sparse voxel octree, but I don't know how to differenciate between branch and leaf nodes effectively.

One way I thought of was to downcast the Node pointers to a child class, but I fear a big performance hit from casting thousand of times

```
struct Node
{
    Node* parent;
};

struct Branch : public Node
{
    Node* children[8];
    unsigned char activeChildren = 0;
};

struct Leaf : public Node
{
    unsigned char color[3];
}
```

Then I read about type unions, but my compiler went wild and I got tons of weird errors when trying to access the unions variables.

```
struct Leaf
{
    unsigned char r = 0;
    unsigned char g = 0;
    unsigned char b = 0;
};

struct Branch
{
    Node* children[8];
    unsigned char activeChildren = 0;
};

union NodeData
{
    Leaf leaf;
    Branch branch;
};

struct Node
{
    Node* parent;
    NodeData data;
};
```

Now I'm thinking about storing the data in a bitmask big enough to fit the biggest node type, and setting an extra bit to know if it's a branch or leaf.

```
class Node
{
public:
    // getter and setter for the nodes content

public:
    Node* parent;

private:
    // bitmask
    // 8*64 bits for pointers to children
    // 8 bit to identify active nodes
    // 
    // 1 bit to identify node type
    // 7 unused bits -> maybe for depth of the node
    unsigned char bitmask[66];
};
```

How would this be handled usually?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I dont really understand the problem, but maybe all you need is `dynamic_cast` or a virtual `bool is_leaf()` method

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number don't I get a big performance hit when dynamic casting every voxel? And with the is_leaf function I'd still have to dynamic cast, right?

Comment: The check if a dynamic_cast will succeed is literally just checking the hidden vptr member. And (for single inheritance) the actual cast itself is literally free, it doesn't require any bytecode at all.

Comment: sidenote: `union` is almost impossible to use correctly. Use `std::variant` instead, which is the same thing, but automatically does all the hard parts.

Comment: when you want to do something (distinguish derived instances) then using the tool for something (dynamic cast) is not "overhead". Its like you want to get a nail into the wall but hesitate to use a hammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:

### 1. Inheritance

Like your original solution. Easy to understand.

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
};

template<typename T>
class Internal<T> : public Node<T> {
    Node<T> *children[8];
};

template<typename T>
class Leaf<T> : public Node<T> {
    T value;
};
```

Speed overhead: either one or more virtual functions or `dynamic_cast`ing.

Size overhead: one vtable pointer, probably 8 bytes on a 64-bits platform.

### 2. A discriminated union

Since the two types of nodes occupy the same bytes in memory, you need to add some way to distinguish which of the types is valid.

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    bool isLeaf;
    union {
        T value;              // Valid if isLeaf
        Node<T> *children[8]; // Valid if !isLeaf
    };
};
```

Speed overhead: a boolean check.

Size overhead: one byte, plus probably 7 bytes of padding on a 64-bits platform.

Advanced idea: if `sizeof(value)` is less than `sizeof(children)` by at least `sizeof(Node<T> *)`, you can avoid the space overhead of the `isLeaf` flag by prepending a null pointer to the value. Then you can check if `children[0] == nullptr` to detect whether it's a leaf. This will usually work, but is technically undefined behaviour.

### 3. No polymorphism at all

Have a single type that contains both data and pointers to child nodes. You can deduce whether it's a leaf by checking `children[0] == nullptr`.

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    bool isLeaf;
    T value;              // Valid if isLeaf
    Node<T> *children[8]; // Valid if !isLeaf
};
```

Speed overhead: a pointer check.

Size overhead: either the value or the child pointers are redundant.

So there really is no advantage compared to solution 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Premature optimization is the root of all evil**

[Check here why](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

You are worrying now about a performance issue that you don't know if it will ever happen. Make your implementation using `dynamic_cast<>` as suggested.

Once your implementation is working, you can benchmark it and see if the casts are really a problem. And I bet they won't be, their implementation is very similar to creating an `isLeaf()` method.